# repeat group header on each page top

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a group header and I need to repeat this on top of every page only.
It should not repeat for all the group values.

Please suggest how to do.

Ex:

Dept : Sales

```
Name    Job     Sal

aa          rer       434
```

Dept : Sales

```
rr         hgh      494
```

Dept : HR

```
rtr        hjggh      49
```

Here  `Name    Job     Sal` headers should repeat top of the each page only.

Comment: Well, your question is not quite clear. In the first line you say

>  "I have a group header and I need to repeat this on top of every page
> only."

Last line you say, 

> Here  `Name    Job     Sal` headers should repeat top of the each page
> only

What do you want repeating on Top of the page, column headers or Group names?? 
Based on the format you have specified, in my opinion your format wont be consistent then. Because Columns Headers `Name    Job     Sal` will be placed under the first group `Dept Sales` and for rest of the groups above the group heading. That is not consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place `Name    Job     Sal` on your `page header` rather than place it on your `group header`, so you will get that info repeated at the top of every new page and not every time the group change.

If you want to keep `Name    Job     Sal` on your group header, create a shared variable on your `page footer` initialized in 0`(example: shared numbervar suppress :=0)`, then place that variable on your group header adding 1 every time the group change`(example: shared numbervar suppress := suppress + 1)`, then right click on your `group header`, `section expert` and place this suppress condition `shared numbervar suppress <> 1`, then `ok` to save, right click on your group header again and go to `change group`, `options tab` and check the option that says `Repeat group header on each page`, then Ok and run the report.